# What costs are incurred when using Cell<T> as opposed to just T?

Tags: rust

I ran across a [comment on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/755a5x/i_have_finally_understood_what_cell_and_refcell/do3tw4c/) that indicates that using `Cell<T>` prevents certain optimizations from occurring:

> Cell works with no memory overhead (Cell is the same size as T) and little runtime overhead (it "just" inhibits optimisations, it doesn't introduce extra explicit operations)

This seems counter to other things I've read about `Cell<T>`, in particular that it's "zero-cost." The first place I encountered this categorization is [here](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2015/05/27/wrapper-types-in-rust-choosing-your-guarantees/).

With all that said, I'd like to understand the actual cost of using `Cell<T>`, including whatever optimizations it may prevent.

Comment: When LLVM knows something is immutable, it can make a lot of optimisations that would be unsafe if that thing turned out to be mutable. Everything is immutable by default in Rust, so the compiler needs to flag to LLVM that it can't just rearrange code however it wants.

Comment: zero cost mean that if you want implement it by hand you will have the same cost of the abstraction. if you need same feature offer `Cell` you will have the same lose of optimisation.

Comment: [Issue #34496](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34496) relates to this, as does the [documentation for `UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) (note that `Cell` itself is not special to the compiler, since it is not a lang item; it "inherits" this property from its internal `UnsafeCell`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR** `Cell` is **Zero-Overhead Abstraction**; that is, the same functionality implemented manually has the same cost.

---

The term **Zero-Cost Abstractions** is not English, it's jargon. The idea of **Zero-Cost Abstractions** is that the *layer of abstraction* itself does not add any cost compared to *manually* doing the same thing.

There are various misunderstandings that have sprung up: most notably, I have regularly seen zero-cost understood as *"the operation is free"*, which is not the case.

To add to the confusion, the exception mechanism used by most C++ implementations, and which Rust uses for `panic = unwind` is called Zero-Cost Exceptions, and purports<sup>1</sup> to add no overhead on the non-throwing path. It's a different kind of Zero-Cost...

Lately, my recommendation is to switch to using the term **Zero-Overhead Abstractions**: first because it's a distinct term from Zero-Cost Exceptions, so less likely to be mistaken, and second because it emphasizes that the Abstraction does not add Overhead, which is what we are trying to convey in the first place.

<sup>1</sup> *The objective is only partially achieved. While the same assembly executed with and without the possibility of throwing indeed has the same performance, the presence of potential exceptions may hinder the optimizer and cause it to generate sub-optimal assembly in the first place.*

---

> With all that said, I'd like to understand the actual cost of using `Cell<T>`, including whatever optimizations it may prevent.

On the memory side, there is no overhead:

- `sizeof::<Cell<T>>() == sizeof::<T>()`,
- given a `cell` of type `Cell<T>`, `&cell == cell.as_ptr()`.

(You can peek [at the source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cell.rs.html#230-232))

On the access side, `Cell<T>` does incur a run-time cost compared to `T`; the cost of the extra functionality.

The most immediate cost is that manipulating the value through a `&Cell<T>` requires copying it back and forth<sup>1</sup>. This is a bitwise copy, so the optimizer *may* elide it, if it can prove that it is safe to do so.

Another notable cost is that `UnsafeCell<T>`, on which `Cell<T>` is based, breaks the rules that `&T` means that `T` cannot be modified.

When a compiler can prove that a portion of memory cannot be modified, it can optimize out further reads: read `t.foo` in a register, then use the register value rather than reading `t.foo` again.

In traditional Rust code, a `&T` gives such a guarantee: no matter if there are opaque function calls, calls to C code, etc... between two reads to `t.foo`, the second read will return the same value as the first, guaranteed. With a `&Cell<T>`, there is no such guarantee any longer, and thus unless the optimizer can prove beyond doubt that the value is unmodified<sup>2</sup>, then it cannot apply such optimizations.

<sup>1</sup> *You can manipulate the value at no cost through `&mut Cell<T>` or using `unsafe` code.*

<sup>2</sup> *For example, if the optimizer knows that the value resides on the stack, and it never passed the address of the value to anyone else, then it can reasonably conclude that no one else can modify the value. Although a stack-smashing attack may, of course.*